# ThreeJS JSON Object Scene format 4

Tags: three.js

I am new to Threejs.

I am trying to understand the JSON structure for JSON Object Scene format 4.

```
"object": {
    "uuid": "89529CC6-CBAC-412F-AFD1-FEEAE785BA19",
    "type": "Scene",
    "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
    "children": [
        {
            "uuid": "33FA38D9-0AAC-4657-9BBE-5E5780DDFB2F",
            "name": "Box 1",
            "type": "Mesh",
            "geometry": "C3BF1E70-0BE7-4E6D-B184-C9F1E84A3423",
            "material": "87D95D6C-6BB4-4B8F-8166-A3A6945BA5E3",
            "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]
        },
        {
            "uuid": "16F2E381-2B73-44C4-A7BB-38D7E1CD2381",
            "name": "PointLight 1",
            "type": "PointLight",
            "color": 16777215,
            "intensity": 1,
            "distance": 0,
            "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,100,200,150,1]
        }
    ]
}
```

"matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,100,200,150,1]

Does this matrix depicts this: "matrix": [xx,xy,xz,?,yx,yy,yz,?,zx,zy,zz,?,px,py,pz,?]

What are the "?" in this matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix property in the JSON refers to the `Object3D.matrix` property which is in fact a 4x4 matrix.

The `Matrix4` class in `three.js` stores its numbers in the `elements` property. It is an array which holds the numbers in column-major order. When a matrix is serialized/deserialized, this order is maintained.

So what you see in the JSON is a serialized 4x4 matrix in column-major order.